# How to select the child <div> element of a div with a particular class-name that is the last div with that class-name in the DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to select all elements of the last parent div in the DOM, my DOM gets created with same repeating classNames , so I want to perform action on all the childrens of matching classNames in the last parent div.
I want to select all the elements with class viewMoreTextButton of the last parent div i.e slick?
I am wondering how to do it, do I need to get the last parent div and loop for same className elemnts or I can use some jQuery built in option.

```
<div class="slick">
    <div id="panel-123">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-789">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-456">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick">
    <div class="panel-890">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-341">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-256">
        <div class="buttondesign">
            <div class="viewMoreWrapper">
                <div class="viewMoreText viewMoreTextSizing">
                    <h4 class="header">Hello</h4>
                    <p class="number"></p><ul><li>Points<br></li><li>Access<br></li><li>Fee<br></li><li>Warranty<br></li><li>Offers</li></ul><p></p>
                    <span id="otp" class="countdown" style="display:none;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="textButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="viewMoreTextButton" onclick="doToggleButton(this);" data-viewmore="" data-viewless="">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: _"my DOM gets created with same repeating ids and classNames"_ - First question should be: "Why are there duplicated ids and how can I fix that?"

Comment: That's how the project is implemented, only one div gets an id that is randomly generated and there are repeated classNames. Let's say for above only div with className panel will be like panel-123 for first div, panel-789 for second div, and soon and all it's parent and children can have same classNames.

Comment: @Andreas I think different divs having same class-names is not an issue. However I should reconsider that element should not have same id, Either I could generate some random no and use it as suffix or prefix with a common name for id e.g cards-123 for first div and cards-456 for second div and soon. However while exploring I have just noticed that Youtube.com has same id="img" for all the thumbnails images for videos, I don't know whether Google uses this or not but yes they all do have the same ids.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are asking your question correctly, but if you simplify it to just the following piece:

- I want to select all the elements with class 'viewMoreTextButton', and do something with them.

That would look like this (jQuery Class Selector):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".viewMoreTextButton").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Note: It helps to put some text in the div and try throwing a simple background color change or 1px solid black border css on whatever you are trying to get when testing selectors (so you can see if you are getting what you want). This will select all of the elements with the class viewMoreTextButton and give them a yellow background.

So then to take this a step further and get the divs with the class viewMoreTextButton to do something such as expand and show more text (as the class name suggests), that would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".viewMoreTextButton").on('click', function () {
    alert('do something that shows more text here...');                
  });
});
```

This will add an on click handler to each element with class viewMoreTextButton that you can use to show more text
by  changing the css of each respective element on click from  none to block or whatever you need.